# All Yeoman generator installations throw massive errors

Tags: node.js, generator, npm, yeoman

I'm having a problem with running generators after installing them through npm. After installing yoeman, grunt and bower as well as any generator, any attempt to run the generator in a new filespace (ie. yo webapp, yo backbone, etc.) results in multiple error messages that I don't understand.

```
Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
  at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1356:32)
  at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:968:10)
  at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:462:15)
  at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
  at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:221:10)
  at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:221:5)
  at EncryptedSteam.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
  at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)

npm ERR! ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Users\ \yo-test\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\mout\array\inser.js'
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\node.js\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\ \yo-test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! path c:\Users\ \yo-test\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\mout\array\insert.js
npm ERR! fstream_path c:\Users\ \yo-test\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\mout\array\insert.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fsteam_class FIleWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! not ok code 0>
```

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

- JD

Comment: Do you happen to use a proxy? Also, please see this [relevant issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/419).

Comment: Yes, all connections to the internet run through a proxy.

Comment: The solution in the link may work, let me try it and then post back.

Comment: I'll add a proper answer, this will be easier for everyone to see it.

Answer (score 1):

The following config in ´~/.bowerrc´seems to solve it:

```
{
    "strict-ssl": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this relevant issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/419#issuecomment-19079006) in bower's Github.

In `~/.bowerrc`, set the endpoint to `http`:

```json
{
  "endpoint": "http://bower.herokuapp.com"
}
```